# Exception handling with Consumer functions in Java 8

Tags: java, exception, lambda

This code gives me a compile error on the line `processBatch(batch, this::backupMetacard);`  The process batch method wraps the consumer in a try/catch block, but Java will not compile the call.

```
private synchronized void drain() {

    for (List<Metacard> batch : Lists.partition(metacards, BATCH_SIZE)) {
        getExecutor().submit(() -> {

            processBatch(batch, this::backupMetacard);
        });
    }
    metacards.clear();
}

void processBatch(List<Metacard> metacards, Consumer<Metacard> operation) {

    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Metacard metacard : metacards) {
        try {
            operation.accept(metacard);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errors.add(metacard.getId());
        }
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.info("Plugin processing failed. This is allowable. Skipping to next plugin.",
                pluginExceptionWith(errors));
    }
}

private void backupMetacard(Metacard metacard) throws IOException {...}
```

Comment: And where is the try-catch part?

Comment: @Tunaki try{} wraps the operation.accept call in the processBatch method.

Comment: A possible issue could be that the function signature doesn't declare that it throws an error. Maybe replace with `void processBatch(List<Metacard> metacards, Consumer<Metacard> operation) throws IOException()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the following snippet, the method `backupMetacard` declares to throw the checked `IOException`.

```
getExecutor().submit(() -> {
    processBatch(batch, this::backupMetacard);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // <-- this throws a checked exception
});
```

As such, it does not comply anymore with the contract of the functional method of [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), which is [`apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-) and doesn't declare to throw checked exceptions.

Wrap this into a `try-catch`, where you can throw an unchecked exception instead [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html):

```
getExecutor().submit(() -> {
    processBatch(batch, metacard -> {
        try {
            backupMetacard(metacard);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works. I was hoping to keep the error handling in the processBatch method because then I could use backupMetacard(), updateMetacard(), deleteMetacard(), ... polymorphically. But it just isn't going to happen so easily.

Answer (score 4):

`Consumer.accept()` does not declare an exception whereas your `backupMetacard` method does, so you can't pass `this::backupMetacard` as `Consumer` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an adapter functional interface

```
interface ConsumerX<T>
{
    void consumeX(T) throws Exception;

    void default consume(T t)
    {
        try{ consumeX(t); }
        catch.... // handle exception
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
processBatch( batch, (ConsumerX<Metacard>)this::backupMetacard )
```

The type argument `<Metacard>` seems redundant, unfortunately it's needed in current Java. We could however have a helper method instead

```
    static <T> ConsumerX<T> of(ConsumerX<T> c){ return c; }

processBatch( batch, ConsumerX.of(this::backupMetacard) )
```

There are more things to consider. Currently, `ConsumerX` throws a fixed, overreaching `Exception`. We would rather have it throw the same exception that the lambda body throws, i.e. exception transparency. This could be done by `consumeX()` throws a type variable.

Another thing is to provide custom exception handling, e.g.

```
    ConsumerX.of( lambda, ex->{ ... } )
```

or my preferred syntax --

```
    ConsumerX.of(...).catch_(FooException.class, fe->{ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are snippet codes that is basically wrapped try-catch block and being consumed Exception object.

```
public static <T> T unchecked(final ExceptionBearingAction<T> template, Consumer<Exception> exceptionConsumer) {
    T results = null;
    try {
        results = template.doAction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        exceptionConsumer.accept(ex);
    }
    return results;
}
```

**ExceptionBearingAction.Java** - It's a Functional Interface that perform and Exception bearing action.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExceptionBearingAction<T> {

   T doAction() throws Exception; 
}
```

**How to used it**

```
unchecked(() -> Files.copy(srcPath, Paths.get(distFileUrl), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING), (ex) -> LOGGER.warn("Oops!! copy failed due to {}", ex));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with apache commons-lang3 library.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/function/Failable.html

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Change method: processBatch

```
void processBatch(List<Metacard> metacards, FailableConsumer<Metacard, IOException> operation) {

    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Metacard metacard : metacards) {
        try {
            operation.accept(metacard);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errors.add(metacard.getId());
        }
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.info("Plugin processing failed. This is allowable. Skipping to next plugin.",
                pluginExceptionWith(errors));
    }
}
```